# JsonConverter in Manatee Json

Tags: json, json.net, manatee.json

I am using Manatee Json for de-/serialization. I want to do use the similar functionality which is available in Netwonsoft where one can override JsonConverter Read and Write Json. Do we have an example on how to do that in Manatee?

Answer (score 0):

Manatee.Json works a bit differently than Json.Net.

With Json.Net, you implement a reader or writer where you translate directly between the JSON and the object.

With Manatee.Json, you don't have to worry about the JSON so much. Instead you translate to a `JsonValue`.

You have a couple primary options on how you can do this:

- If you own the object (you have the *.cs* file for it), the best approach is to have it implement `IJsonSerializable`.  The serializer prioritizes for this.
- If you don't own the object, you can create an `ISerializer` implementation to perform the translation.

The [serialization docs](https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/usage/serialization.html) give a lot more detail.